# Left join and not exists

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a scenario in which I have 5 tables with different columns.

If I join `Table1` and `table2` I get result `A` and joining `table3`, `table4`, `table5` I get result `B`.

I need to compare result `A` with result `B` and display the results `A` **which are not in** result `B`

I tried this:

```
 SELECT X* 
    FROM 
    (SELECT .. 
     FROM table1
      JOIN TABLE 2)X
  LEFT JOIN 
     (SELECT ...
          FROM TABLE 3
           JOIN 4 
           JOIN 5) Y ON x.=y.
 WHERE x.Z=''
```

But this does not give me the desired result. I tried using not exists and I cannot do a not exists.

Can I get any assistance for this.

> 

I tried the suggested query with the following modifications but i am still unable to make up to my requirement

```
> select x.column1,
         x.column2,
         x.column3,
         y.column4
>       from 
>     (select table1.column1 column1,table1.column2 column2,table2.column1 column3
>      from table1
>       join table 2)X   left join 
>      (select table3.column1 column4,table3.column2 column5,table4.column1 column1 6
>           from table 3
>            join 4 
>                 ) y on x.column1=y.column4  where y.COLUMN4 IS NULL
```

As per my requirement i need to show only those results from X that do not exist in Y.

But the current query above works as follows ,
 displays all the results from X even though there are 0 results in Y.

I am not sure where i am going wrong.

Comment: *i cannot do a not exists* any reason ?

Comment: because i need to display few columns of y in the result if required later. Hence using a not exist in the where condition doesn't serve the purpose though it fulfills the condition

Comment: did you try WHERE whatever_condition NOT IN()? also try changing your LEFT JOIN to LEFT OUTER JOIN so there is no filtering at all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

General approach to exclude B from A is following

```
SELECT * FROM A LEFT JOIN B on A.ID = B.ID WHERE B.ID IS NULL
```

In your case it probably should be

```
select x* 
    from 
    (select .. 
     from table1
      join table 2)X
  left join 
     (select ...
          from table 3
           join 4 
           join 5) y on x.COLUMN=y.COLUMN
 where x.Z='' and y.COLUMN IS NULL
```

UPDATE:
General approach get all rows from A if some condition is true is:

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE your_condition
```

In your case it probably should be

```
select x* 
    from 
    (select .. 
     from table1
      join table 2)X
  left join 
     (select ...
          from table 3
           join 4 
           join 5) y on x.COLUMN=y.COLUMN
 where x.Z='' and y.COLUMN IS NULL
and (select count(*) from Y) > 0
```

Comment: I tried the suggested query with the following modifications but i am still unable to make up to my requirement

Comment: As per my requirement i need to show only those results from X that do not exist in Y. 
But the current query above works as follows , displays all the results from X even though there are 0 results in Y.
 
I am not sure where i am going wrong.

Comment: "current query above works as follows , displays all the results from X even though there are 0 results in Y" - it is the way how it should work. It shows those results from X that do not exist in Y. If Y is empty it should show all rows from X.

Comment: any suggestions that i can get for the approach that i need to follow to get only those results from X that do not match with Y. if there are no results in Y then it should give me 0 results over all else only those from X that do not match with Y.

Comment: So you need "exists in Y but do not match"?

Comment: i need to display the results from X the do not match with the results from Y. And if there are no results in Y to compare with X then the overall result set should be null